# Play audio during a phone call

Tags: android, phone-call

I saw many posts regarding this issue but all of them are from a few years ago.
Would like to ask again whether anything has changed? Is it possible today to play sound during a phone call?

What I want to do is to use android text-to-speech and play it during a phone call. 
I tried to turn on the speaker and play it but the other side does not hear it.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this? https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006983?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can not play in-call audio streaming. MediaPlayer api's are not allowing to do.

This is mentioned in [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) overview

**Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during a call.**